# I need help removing gaps in a list that skips numbers

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, list-comprehension

```py
polygons = {}
removed = 0

with open("Polygon.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        if row[5] == "Color Hex":
            pass
        else:
            if checkred(row[5]) == True:
                removed += 1
                isremoved = True
                continue
            else:
                isremoved = False
                
        is_triangle = row[0] == "Polygon"
        if row[0] == "Rectangle" or is_triangle:
                poly_id = int(row[1])
```

This is the important code from my program. `checkred()` is a function that determines whether a hex value is red or not and returns True or False. Each time the function is red I need to skip the rest of the code and go back to the beginning for loop, so some numbers are skipped in the output:

```
{
    [2] = {
        ["verts"] = {-178,300,-60,426,-300,434,-300,434},
        ["color"] = {0,71,72,255}
    },
    [3] = {
        ["verts"] = {480,676,436,824,648,798,648,798},
        ["color"] = {0,73,74,255}
    },
    [4] = {
        ["verts"] = {-206,682,-50,792,-276,830,-276,830},
        ["color"] = {0,72,72,255}
    },
    [5] = {
        ["verts"] = {-238,454,-56,408,-192,328,-192,328},
        ["color"] = {0,26,26,255}
    },
    [6] = {
        ["verts"] = {422,770,542,832,570,716,570,716},
        ["color"] = {0,41,42,255}
    },
    [7] = {
        ["verts"] = {400,424,532,300,638,434,638,434},
        ["color"] = {0,71,71,255}
    },
    [8] = {
        ["verts"] = {452,352,534,458,568,342,568,342},
        ["color"] = {0,23,23,255}
    },
    [9] = {
        ["verts"] = {-74,786,-208,834,-208,708,-208,708},
        ["color"] = {0,22,21,255}
    },
    [13] = {
        ["verts"] = {506,708,616,792,486,830,486,830},
        ["color"] = {0,19,19,255}
    },
    [14] = {
        ["verts"] = {-264,772,-226,722,-208,812,-208,812},
        ["color"] = {71,172,173,255}
    },
    [18] = {
        ["verts"] = {-178,446,-218,372,-146,334,-146,334},
        ["color"] = {0,0,0,255}
    },
```

The number in brackets is `poly_id`. How do I reparse this to keep the output in order counting from 1 despite iterations being skipped?

Comment: Subtract `int(row[1])` with `removed` and store it in `poly_id`. That should solve your problem.

Comment: Very hard to understand what's going on here without more information, in particular the input (sample), and more connect between text and program.

Comment: The input is a csv file with over 7000 rows it’s iterating through, but what the program does doesn’t really have much to do with the issue

Comment: Also subtracting `removed` from `int(row[1])` causes the numbers to go negative